# J19 Pin on Ultimaker 2 Mainboard Marlin Config

Tags: marlin, ultimaker-2

[image]

I am trying to configure an Ultimaker 2 (go) with Marlin. My current hotend is a 1.75 mm E3D V6 (still bowden), and the extruder fan uses J19 24V, as circled in green in the picture. Whenever I turn on the printer, the extruder fan keeps running no matter what, and regardless of the temperature. This is kind of annoying, as I want to leave the printer on along with setting it up with Octoprint. So, in Marlin, I want to find the pin number so I can configure it as a proper extruder fan, so it isn't running constantly. I tried M43, but it didn't list J19.

(Just plain Marlin with config, not the specific Ultimaker-specific marlin )